# React-Native Navigation 5 - Element type is Invalid expected a string or a class/function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Keep getting `Element type is invalid` with `NavigationNativeContainer` & `Stack.Navigator`, I have checked the code many times. Can anyone help plz.

```
import React from 'react';

import { NavigationNativeContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Login from './login';
import DashboardUI from './kitchen-counter/dashboard';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationNativeContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name={'Login'} component={() => <Login />}
          options={{
            title: 'Meal Night Kitchen Login',
            headerTitleAlign: 'center'
          }} />

        <Stack.Screen
          name={'Dashboard'}
          component={() => <DashboardUI />}
          options={{ title: 'Manage your account', headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerLeft: null }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationNativeContainer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I am really stuck, plz help if anyone can. thank you.

Comment: Are you having default exports for Login and DashboardUI ?

Comment: sure. both login and dashboard component also has export default

Comment: its NavigationContainer not NavigationNativeContainer

Comment: yes, its is. My god. Going to see the eye doctor after this mate. Thanks a lot. Really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import is wrong you are using NavigationNativeContainer instead of NavigationContainer

It should be

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

When you try to render something that is not defined you will be the error 'Element type is invalid'.

Answer (score 0):

its suppose to be `NavigationContainer` not `NavigationNativeContainer`. When react-navigation was in beta, it was `NavigationNativeContainer` . Thanks to @guruparan Giritharan. The entire credit goes to him.